# Fulton's pullback vs. Pullback via Gersten complexes vs. Pullback coming from motivic homotopy SH(k)

Tags: motivic-cohomology, motivic-homotopy, chow-groups

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of smooth projective $k$-schemes (let's assume $f$ flat or even smooth). There is pullback in Fulton's style $f^*_{Ful}: CH^p(Y) \rightarrow CH^p(X)$ given by $[Z] \mapsto [f^{-1}Z]$.On the other hand, we have a Bloch-Quillen-Kerz isomorphism $$BQ: CH^p(X) \stackrel{\cong}{\rightarrow} H^p_{Nis}(X,K^M_p),$$
where the right-hand side denotes the Nisnevich cohomology of the Milnor $K$-theory sheaf, which can be computed by Gersten's resolution. We also have the pullback of complexes in Rost's style $f^*: C^*(Y,K^M_p) \rightarrow C^*(X,K^M_p)$, which gives us a pullback on cohomology 
$$f_{R}^*: H^p_{Nis}(Y,K^M_p) \rightarrow H^p_{Nis}(X,K^M_p).$$
We also can represent the Chow group in the stable motivic homotopy category as 
$$Rep_{M}: CH^p(X) \stackrel{\cong}{\rightarrow} SH(k)[\Sigma^{\infty}_{T,+}X,M\mathbb{Z}\wedge S^{2p,p}].$$
There is a pullback 
$$f^*_{Ho}: SH(k)[\Sigma^{\infty}_{T,+}Y,M\mathbb{Z}\wedge S^{2p,p}] \rightarrow SH(k)[\Sigma^{\infty}_{T,+}X,M\mathbb{Z}\wedge S^{2p,p}], \alpha \mapsto \alpha \circ \Sigma^{\infty}_{T,+}(f).$$

My questions are:

(1) Are they $f^*_{Ful}, f^*_R$ and $f^*_{Ho}$ compatible via $BQ$ and $Rep_M$?

(2) Assume furthermore that $f$ is projective, we can define also the pushforwards $f^{Ful}_*, f^R_*$ and $f^{Ho}_*$, where the last one is defined via duality/Thom isomorphism. Are they also compatible with each other via $BQ$ and $Rep_M$?

Thank you very much.

PS: The reason for my question is the theorem of Voevodsky, which confirms that there is an fully faithful embedding $Chow(k) \rightarrow DM(k)$. I don't see anywhere in his proof, that the composition law in $Chow(k)$ is compatible with the one in $DM(k)$

Comment: I believe that the answers to your questions are positive.:) Which text of Voevodsky are you reading? Did you try to read Mazza C., Voevodsky V.,  Weibel Ch., " Lecture notes on motivic cohomology", Clay Mathematics Monographs, vol. 2, 2006?